# Whats the Functional difference between the Setup vs the Auto update Offline Setup Installer files of Opera Browser?

Tags: installation, browser, opera, setup, installer

http://get.geo.opera.com.global.prod.fastly.net/pub/opera/desktop/ 
http://get.geo.opera.com.global.prod.fastly.net/pub/opera/desktop/50.0.2762.67/win/

```
Index of /pub/opera/desktop/50.0.2762.67/win/
../
patch/                                             22-Jan-2018 12:55                   -
Opera_50.0.2762.67_Autoupdate.exe                  22-Jan-2018 12:55            37604416
Opera_50.0.2762.67_Autoupdate_x64.exe              22-Jan-2018 12:55            43281792
Opera_50.0.2762.67_Setup.exe                       22-Jan-2018 12:55            39766536
Opera_50.0.2762.67_Setup_x64.exe                   22-Jan-2018 12:55            46078280
```

Comment: @Biswapriyo - I just moved Opera Browser from Start of phrasing to end.. Does it make you happy?

Answer (score -1):

First, how to get that direct download link of Opera browser? Open Opera computer browser download link https://www.opera.com/computer in any browser. Click on the small blue link says, 'Download the offline package'. Don't download the installer. Right click on the 'try again' option and copy the link location. Put that link in `curl --head` command as an argument. The output shows the redirected download link of the setup executable. Here is an example (link may change in future):

```
$> curl --head "https://www.opera.com/download/get/?id=43797&amp;location=411&amp;nothanks=yes&amp;sub=marine&utm_tryagain=yes"
HTTP/2 302
date: Sat, 21 Jul 2018 13:37:34 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
location: https://download1.operacdn.com/pub/opera/desktop/54.0.2952.60/win/Opera_54.0.2952.60_Setup.exe
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

The link mentioned in question http://get.geo.opera.com.global.prod.fastly.net/pub/opera/desktop/ seems to be older than the above https://download1.operacdn.com/pub/opera/desktop/ link (CDN means Content Delivery Network). But they point towards same file.

Now, how to find the difference between those two 'AutoUpdate' and 'Setup' file? For this, we need [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) tool. Use `7z t` command to get details of those two files:

```
$> 7z t Opera_54.0.2952.60_Autoupdate_x64.exe
$> 7z t Opera_54.0.2952.60_Setup_x64.exe
```

Alternatively, use [`file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) in *nix systems. Here are the output:

```
$> file Opera_54.0.2952.60_Autoupdate_x64.exe
Opera_54.0.2952.60_Autoupdate_x64.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows

$> file Opera_54.0.2952.60_Setup_x64.exe
Opera_54.0.2952.60_Setup_x64.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Here are the main differences. The Setup is a normal executable file. Users have to go through the setup process, accept license and terms, choose installation path, click 'yes' etc. But the Autoupdate is a [SFX file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) aka. Self Extracting Archive. The 7zip output will show this: `FileDescription: Opera installer SFX`. So, when user double click on that Autoupdate file it will be automatically extracted the Opera browser executable ans associated DLL files in that containing folder without the setup procedure as mentioned above. As the setup contains more data for installation procedure, that file is bigger that the Autoupdate file. Both have same `LZMA:192m BCJ2` compression method but the execution is different. Both files can be extracted with `7z x` command.

Comment: The links I posted allow one to go to specific releases and versions, even older ones if one prefers. So let's focus on that.

Comment: What is the "functional difference"? I was hoping for someone who knows Opera to point out why they have the 2 variations and what & how they do differently.. not necessarily their Archive formats & contents. FUNCTION & REASON to USE one vs ANOTHER and difference in overall outcome if any

Comment: @AlexS I said that. Setup requires some step to install and SFX doesn't. And SFX easy to install. And both links are pointing towards same file. No difference.